# Doctrine command line insert with preUpdate, prePersist

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I can insert data in database controlled by Doctrine directly use SQL.

```
php bin/console doctrine:query:sql \
    "INSERT INTO meta_info(app_title,enabled) VALUES('mapapp',1)"
```

However my entity has like this `preUpdate()`, `prePersist()`

So I want to insert with DQL, not using SQL directly.

Is there any way to do this?

```
/**
* @ORM\PreUpdate
*/
public function preUpdate()
{
    $this->updatedAt = new \DateTime;
}
/**
* @ORM\PrePersist
*/
public function prePersist(){

    $this->createdAt = new \DateTime;
    $this->updatedAt = new \DateTime;
}
```

Comment: So create a command and insert via entityManager, no?

Comment: Whitebear, any feedback on the answer below?

Comment: Keep in mind, that using DQL does *not* trigger `@ORM\PreUpdate` https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/events.html#lifecycle-events

Answer (score 1):

> So I want to insert with DQL not SQL directly.

While a command exist for DQL queries (`doctrine:query:dql`), DQL does not support `INSERT` queries, as you can see [in the docs](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#doctrine-query-language).

Your best option would be would be to [write your own console command](https://symfony.com/doc/current/console.html#creating-a-command), inject the entity manager, and create and persist the entity there.

A very simple command would go something like this:

```
class FooCreate extends Command {

    protected static $defaultName = 'foo:entity:create';
    /**
     * @var EntityManagerInterface
     */
    private $manager;

    public function __construct( EntityManagerInterface $manager ) {
        $this->manager = $manager;
        parent::__construct();
    }

      protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output): int
    {
        $entity = new Entity('app_title', 'enabled');
        $this->manager->persist($entity);
        $this->manager->flush();

    }
}
```

Which you would call `console foo:entity:create`.